# Use sed with a special char inside string

Tags: shell, sed, char, space, symbols

I have a special char "&" in a string, how can use sed?
Space before symbol `&` is the issue.

```
word="Word"
str="Word: One \\& Three" 
echo "$str" | sed -e 's/'$word'.*/'$str'/g'
```

Comment: use `"$word"` instead of `'$word'` and same for `$str`..and I dnt think you need to enclose the entire `sed` command in `'....'`

Comment: Needs clarification: is the string the input, the regexp or the replacement? What is significant about the "space before symbol `&`"? The answer is difficult depending on these details.

Answer (score 2):

If you use single quotes `'`, shell will not be able to expand the variables as it will be treated literally.

You can interpolate variables by doing:

**- Double quotes:**

Using double quotes `"` shell will expand your variables and preserve whitespace.

```
 sed -e "s/$word.*/$str/g"
```

**- Single quotes:**

If you have lot of special characters, use single quotes for pattern and double quotes the variables.

```
sed -e 's/'"$word"'.*/'"$str"'/g'
```